# In Romans 1:4, what is the meaning of the phrase «πνεῦμα ἁγιωσύνης»?

Tags: greek, romans

In [Rom. 1:4](https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/rom/1/4/t_conc_1047004), it is written,

> And declared to be the Son of God with power, according to **the spirit of holiness**, by the resurrection from the dead: <sup>KJV, 1769</sup>
>
> τοῦ ὁρισθέντος υἱοῦ θεοῦ ἐν δυνάμει κατὰ **πνεῦμα ἁγιωσύνης** ἐξ ἀναστάσεως νεκρῶν Ἰησοῦ Χριστοῦ τοῦ κυρίου ἡμῶν <sup>TR, 1550</sup>

What is the meaning of the phrase «πνεῦμα ἁγιωσύνης»? Does it refer to the Holy Spirit or to something else?

Answer (score 1):

According to three different Greek Church Fathers, Paul is referring to the Holy Spirit here.

Cyril of Jerusalem refers to this verse in his *17th Catechetical Lecture* ("Continuation of the Discourse on the Holy Ghost"):

> Thou wilt find many other titles of the Holy Ghost besides.  Thus He
>   is called the Spirit of Holiness, as it is written, *According to the
>   Spirit of Holiness*<sup>1</sup>

Basil the Great also refers to the verse in his discourse, *On the Spirit*:

> You expect to be glorified together with Christ; (“if so be that we
>   suffer with him that we may be also glorified together;” [Romans
>   8:17]) but you do not glorify the “Spirit of holiness” together with
>   Christ, as though He were not worthy to receive equal honour even with
>   you.  You hope to “reign with” [2 Timothy 2:12] Christ; but you “do
>   despite unto the Spirit of grace” [Hebrews 10:29] by assigning Him the
>   rank of a slave and a subordinate.<sup>2</sup>

He also paraphrases Romans 1:4 in referring to the Holy Spirit as the "fount of holiness" in one of his Epistles.<sup>3</sup>

Finally, a later Greek writer, John of Damascus, also interprets the verse in this way, writing:

> [Other sayings] again are for the purpose of revealing Him to us and
>   strengthening our faith, as, And now, O Father, glorify Thou Me with
>   the glory which I had with Thee, before the world was [John 17:5]. For
>   He Himself was glorified and is glorified, but His glory was not
>   manifested nor confirmed to us. Also that which the apostle said,
>   Declared to be the Son of God with power, according to the spirit of
>   holiness, by the resurrection from the dead [Romans 1:4]. For by the
>   miracles and the resurrection and the coming of the Holy Spirit it was
>   manifested and confirmed to the world that He is the Son of
>   God.<sup>4</sup>

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup>[Lecture XVII.5](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf207.ii.xxi.html)</sup>
<sup>2</sup>  <sup>[Chapter XXVIII](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf208.vii.xxix.html), "That our opponents refuse to concede in the case of the Spirit the terms which Scripture uses in the case of men, as reigning together with Christ", Article 70</sup>
<sup>3</sup> <sup>[Epistle VIII.10](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf208.ix.ix.html)</sup>
<sup>4</sup>  <sup>[*Exact Exposition of the Orthodox Faith*, IV.XVIII](https://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/npnf209.iii.iv.iv.xviii.html)</sup>